# callApi with Login to access .json File - vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

i want to access a .json file via link.
when i type in the link to my json file in my browser, it asks for credentials (username + password) which i know.

i want to write the credentials in the code, so i dont have to log in manually anymore,
OR
**get a message to log in with my credentials when the website is trying to fetch the data from the json file.**

of course if there are other possibilities to access the json other than a callApi method you're welcome. :)

present code without authentication and with a local file:

```
<script>
import jsonData from '../../static/json/test.json'
export default {
  name: 'dash',
  data() {
    return {
      data: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      this.callApi()
        .then((responseData) => {
          this.data = responseData;

        })
    },
    callApi() {
      return Promise.resolve(jsonData)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using basic authentication you can add your username and password in the beginning of the url separated by a colon. So an example url would be https://username:password@www.example.com/

Note that this is not a good practice and should not be used in production.

Comment: I tried that, and got the following error:
Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials.